Who produces this board and where can I find a circuit diagram/ data sheet?
I have this circuit board from a rear bicycle light. I want to know who produces them so I can find a circuit diagram and data sheet.
It has a logo on it and the text: RCY-1 94V-0   STEADY REAR V01


It would be easier to reverse-engineer the board yourself, most likely. If it's a cheap bike light it almost certainly is just a two-layer board with only a handful of components, and you may be able to trace out what connects where without even using a multimeter.

I agree with @Hearth! Even if this device had some fancy functionality (which I doubt, with the product name "STEADY REAR"), it would likely be a black epoxy blob COB that did the "thinking business", so would be hard to reproduce, but easy to re-engineer.

The RU mark does not signify a specific manufacturer.

image from https://markshub.ul.com/north-america-geography
It's The UL "Recognized Component Mark". According to UL "It is used on components that are part of a larger UL Certified product or system." Though it only means that the component that bears the mark is a recognized part, meaning it is designed to go be compliant with UL standards such that it can be used in a UL certified system - it does not mean that the system is automatically UL certified.
It is a marking meant for components that goes into other components as installed "at the factory", not in the field.
The marking comes in three variations, the one as above, one with a preceding "C", and one with a preceding "C" and trailing "US".
The first means it's compliant with the US UL standards, the one with the "C" means the component is compliant with Canadian standards, and is only used in the Canadian market, and the cRUus-one means the component is compliant to both US and Candadian standards and are valid for both the US and Canada.
You can read more about the UL marking scheme on UL Marks and label Hub
The "94V-0" marking in the text on the board signifies the flammability of the circuit board. It means that the material of the pcb has been tested against the UL94 stanard, and to the performance requirement V-0, burning on a vertical specimen stops within 10 seconds, and the drops of burning particles should not get inflamed.

More specifically, it's used on components that are intended and pre-certified for use in a larger UL certified system; the presence of this mark does not imply that the whole system is UL certified.

https://markshub.ul.com/north-america-geography

@Hearth Good point. I specifically used the wording as chosen by UL themselves, but I agree, it's actually slightly ambiguous.

Is there maybe a platform you can search to find this specific circuit board. With its text on there and the number (style like seven segment displays show) 085?

There is a database for UL certified end products, it can be found on https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en but whether that also contains subassemblies/registered components? I would be surprised. That's typically protected IP for the manufacturer of the certifed end product.
